# Calculate letter grade using a series of grades

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Noob to Ruby here.  Working through some exercises and have hit a wall.

Exercise: Calculate the letter grade of a series of grades

Create a method get_grade that accepts an Array of test scores. Each score in the array should be between 0 and 100, where 100 is the max score.

Compute the average score and return the letter grade as a String, i.e., 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', or 'F'.

I keep returning the **error**:

```
avg.rb:1: syntax error, unexpected tLBRACK, expecting ')'
def get_grade([100,90,80])
               ^
avg.rb:1: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting $end
```

Here's what I have so far. I'd like to stick with the methods below or .join as I'm trying to work with the methods we're learning in class.  So sum, inject, etc won't necessarily be helpful.  And I apologize in advance for the specificity of the request :) I'm sure there's a way better way that is way less code, but I'm just trying to learn it this way to start.

```
    def get_grade([100,90,80])
      get_grade = (array[0] + array[1] + array[2]).to_i / array.length.to_i
    case get_grade
      when 90..100
      "A"
      when 80..90
       "B"
      when 70..80
       "C"
      when 60..70
       "D"
      when 0..60
       "F"
      else
     "Error"
      end
    end

    puts get_grade([100,90,80])
```

Answer (score 7):

You can't just randomly dump an array literal like `[100,90,80]` into the parameter list of a function definition. Judging by the function body, I think you meant to accept a single parameter `array`:

```
def get_grade(array)
  grade = (array[0].to_i + array[1].to_i + array[2].to_i) / array.length
  case grade
    # unchanged
  end
end
```

Comment: In addition, the calculation of the grade could be slightly improved: `array.inject(:+) / array.size`.

Comment: @BenjaminTan I know, and I'd love to; but quoting the question: "I'd like to stick with the methods below or .join as I'm trying to work with the methods we're learning in class. So sum, inject, etc won't necessarily be helpful."

Comment: True, but I really couldn't resist. :)

Comment: So I would say neither of the `.to_i`s are useful to you here. If you don't have integers on the left then the addition probably isn't going to work correctly, and if you have an array on the right then .length will already be an integer. Personally if you *have* to test for integers then I would try `(array[0].to_i + array[1].to_i + array[2].to_i) / array.length`

Comment: @Gareth That was copypasta from the question. I'll fix it now.

Comment: Hey Gents,Thanks for the feedback. For some reason Rspec is still giving me an error when a value that falls in the B range is returned as well as the C range.  It's pretty strange.  Additionally, I also realized that this method is limited to arrays with 3 arguments, what would a method look like for arbitrary arrays look like?

Comment: @NicholasJayanty The most likely cuplrit for the Rspec error is the `..` range operator. Using `...` instead excludes the endpoint of the range, so try changing all `..`s to `...`s (**except the first**). As for arbitrary arrays, well, you need `inject`.

Answer (score 1):

A terse replacement of the big `case` statement, for fun:

```
def letter_grade( score ) # assumes that score is between 0 and 100 (not 0-1)
  %w[F F F F F F D C B A][ (score/10.0).floor ] || 'A' # handles grades >=100
end
```

Or, for more granularity:

```
def letter_grade( score ) # score is between 0 and 100 (not 0-1)
  grades = %w[F F F F F F F F F F F F F F F F F F D- D D+ C- C C+ B- B B+ A- A A+ A+]
  grades[ (3.0*score/10).floor ]
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help today! Here's what I ended up doing to make it work with more than just 3 arguments. I used an Array#each method.  I imagine there's a more elegant solution out there, but it worked! Worked on this since 10:00 AM, greatly appreciate the help!

```
def get_grade(array)
     sum = 0
   array.each do |element|
    sum += element
   end
   average = sum / array.length
    if average >= 90
      grade = "A"
    elsif average >= 80
      grade = "B"
    elsif average >= 70
     grade = "C"
   elsif average >= 60
     grade = "D"
   elsif average >= 0
    grade = "F"
   else
   "Error"
   end
end

puts get_grade([70,80,80,90,100])
puts get_grade([100,80,90,11,20])
puts get_grade([30,20,10,60,75])
```

Comment: Looking forward to learning more about .inject as I saw it listed as a solution for this question on several boards! Any links about it are appreciated as I couldn't find it in the ruby-docs methods documentation.

Comment: `inject` is part of the `Enumerable` mixin you can see the documentation here http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html

Answer (score 0):

Remember that the max score is 100 (and it can be assumed that the min is 0).

```
def get_grade(array)
sum = 0
array.each do |x|
    sum += x
end

average = sum / array.length

if average > 100
  print "Grades must be no more than 100!"
elsif average >= 90
  grade = "A"
elsif average >= 80
  grade = "B"
elsif average >= 70
  grade = "C"
elsif average >= 60
  grade = "D"
elsif average >=0
  grade = "F"
else 
  print "Grades must be no less than 0!"
end
grade
    end

puts get_grade([100,90,80]) == "A"
puts get_grade([98,90,80]) == "B"
puts get_grade([80,80,80]) == "B"
puts get_grade([55,45,35]) == "F"
puts get_grade([101,100,104]) 
puts get_grade([-2,-3,-4])
```

Answer (score 0):

Added a proc so that even if a user enters a score over 100 it won't be calculated into the average. 
Also refactored the switch statements to one line each. Let me know if this helps. Good luck.

```
  def get_grade array
    scores_under_100 = Proc.new {|score| score <= 100 && score > 0} 
    scores = array.select(&scores_under_100)
    average = scores.inject(:+) / scores.size

    case average
      when 90..100 then puts "A."
      when 80..89 then puts "B."
      when 70..79 then puts "C."
      when 60..69 then puts "D."
      else puts "F."
    end
  end

 puts get_grade([100, 100, 90, 67, 85, 200, 290, 299, 299])
```

Comment: @michaelb958 know you wanted to stay away from object method, but I think this is still a solid way to pass an array of as many scores as you'd like.